# Compatibilty of the following softwares

Tags: centos, rhel, compatibility

I am a professor (Mechanical Engineering department) at a college which is making the transition from Windows to Linux. However, we are quite unsure whether all the CAE softwares that we use would be compatible with Linux.

The list of 13 softwares that we currently use are listed below : 
Solid Edge,
Uni Graphics,
Hyperworks,
CATIA,
ANSYS,
FLUENT,
GAMBIT,
MATLAB,
AutoCAD,
ABAQUS,
ADAMS,
NASTRAN, and
STAAD PRO.

Which would be the best choice of OS for my college? Red Hat Enterprise Linux or CentOS? Of the little research that I did, I came to know that some work in RHEL, which is a paid distribution.

Another query of mine is whether a software would work in CentOS if it works in RHEL? Also, what about Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: I can only answer for CentOS and RedHat: both are identical (read 100% compatible) as CentOS is a community version based on RHEL sources. Both are interchangeable.